# DataGridView CellValidated Event When Formatted Value is Nothing

Tags: vb.net, winforms, datagridview

I have a DatagridView in my Winform and i can change all cells's value.
I would like to save the new cell's value with the CellValidated Event with the FormattedValue. Its works but when i change a cell empty, FormattedValue is empty too.

This is my code :

```
    Try
        If IsDBNull(e.GridCell.FormattedValue) = False Then
            If e.GridCell.FormattedValue.Trim <> "" Then
                ExecuteSql("UPDATE ...")                    
            Else
                ExecuteSql("DELETE ...")
            End If
        End If
    Catch ex As Exception
        ...
    End Try
```

Comment: Why do you not use the `CellValueChanged` event ?

Comment: Because when i will load data, all values will change so all cells will save, that no what i want.

Comment: CellValueChanged only fires when the cell value is really modified by UI. Did you try to use this event ?

Comment: Yes its works, my bad so i thought that will be slow. Thank you !